# SQL : keep count in row or select count from db

Tags: php, mysql

example : i have 2 tables 
- Categories
- Posts

is it a good way to keep post number in categories like this

**categories**

```
 id |  title   | posts
----+----------+--------
 1  | golf     |  50
----+----------+-------
 2  | soccer   |  90
----+----------+-------
```

**posts**

```
 id |  title   | category_id
----+----------+--------------
 1  | news 1   |  1
----+----------+--------------
 2  | news 2   |  2
----+----------+--------------
 3  | news 3   |  1
----+----------+--------------
```

or i use select count() in queries like this

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.title,
       count(p.id)
FROM `categories` c
INNER JOIN `posts` p ON c.id=p.category_id
GROUP BY c.id
```

but the problem is when i keep count in categories table when post change category i have to update posts field in categories table too. it's no problem in small project but for big project what is the good way to deal with count because i concern about database performance

thanks for all answers

Comment: for large project, good idea to store count into categories table

Comment: If there are more Read operations than write, then storing the count in table will be more beneficial.

Comment: this is often a tradeoff. Some folks simply update those summ-tables on every action performend (insert/delete) so the numbers stay accurate and keep a logging table what actions are done on each day and nightly check (jobs) are run to check if the numbers are still accurate. Others simply use count() on live data - but as you already stated this will run into a performance issue. I would aim for some sort of caching. Store the current category count for some time in your application layer and update it only every 15 minutes. No one will be angry because the counts are not 100% live.

Comment: it would be better to store the posts count in CATEGORY table and update everytime. Bcoz everytime when you fetch the posts count you have to make a JOIN to posts table and count the posts. This may slow the response.

Answer (score 2):

My personal preference would be not to keep duplicated data in any table, until it has been proven necessary. If you are averse to writing `JOIN` queries, you could define a view that contains the query and you can then forget about it.

I have found in the past that proper indexes usually mean there isn't too much of a performance problem with this.

If you find it necessary to keep a count summary your `categories` table (for performance or other reasons), consider creating `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` triggers on your `posts` table so that updates can be done by the database rather than relying on the application programmers to remember what has to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Dr. Dan's comment is correct.
It is indeed a good idea to store the count of posts in categories, but remember that if you do that "You must also have triggers to increment and decrement the count when new post is inserted or existing post is deleted" to maintain the integrity.

Answer (score 1):

This, in general depends on your use-case.

From the pure view, of course, you should not introduce redundancy, so your proposed query would be the way to go. However, you might hit some performance problems.

A second approach would be to have a trigger on the posts-table which maintains the posts-counter in categories, but this might also impact performance if there are lots of inserts/deletes in the posts-table.

Another approach would be to have some dirty-flag, which if set causes an update to the categories-table.

So how to proceed? First try out the pure and clean thing, if that hits performance issues, analyze your usage-profile and act depending on that.

Answer (score 1):

I Guess you have to use `JOIN` between the two tables and `GROUP BY` for the posts

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly point out, you know that you'll introduce a maintenance issue if you store the count separately.

Ideally, you should be determining counts dynamically.  With the proper indexes in place this shouldn't be a huge ask for most systems.

However, there are cases where a pre-calculated count makes a lot of sense.  Consider a system that refreshes its data on a chronological cycle.  Apart from the refresh activity, nothing else inserts information into the system.  This sort of system would be perfect for pre-calculated counts.

Looking at your issue specifically, you don't seem to have that option.  This looks to be something rather "bloggy", and as a consequence, is something where the counts could change all the time.

If it were me, I'd start out the dynamic count route, horse-trading down to pre-calculated if and when dynamic becomes a problem.

Comment: "With the proper indexes...." - if there are less than 30 or so categories and/or the data is not evenly distributed, then an index on category will slow the system down not speed it up.