# Store summary data at master table, instead of deriving it

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-apex

I am trying to prepare DB design for APEX application. Requirement is as follows.

In Departments IR page, users are asking below columns

1. Number of employees in each department (Department may or may not have employees)
2. Primary Location for Department (Department can have multiple addresses and addresses are stored in other table, along with primary flag)
3. Alternative Manager's Email Address for Department (alt_manager_id column, this is optional column and refers to employees table)

I can implement these requirements using either inline sub queries or using OUTER JIONs. But, these approaches will have performance impact as the data grows (like 100s of thousands of rows). So, my question is, is it ok to store these data directly at "Departments" table and update "Departments" table when child tables gets updated. Basically, I am trying to store summary data at master table, instead of deriving it as on when needed from child tables. Is this considered bad practice? Is it ok to implement such DB design?

Thank you

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL : keep count in row or select count from db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929356/sql-keep-count-in-row-or-select-count-from-db) (Just the first I found, not the earliest or very highly upvoted.)

Answer (score 1):

> "Is this considered bad practice?"

Usually yes. There are several problems with maintaining summary detail information in a master record.

1. Your inserts into child tables (and deletes if you have them) now also have to take a lock on the master record, to increment the count. This adds complexity to what should be simple transactions.
2. It also has two performance hits: the additional overhead of maintaining the counts and the potential for sessions to hang in multi-user environments.

Note that you are adding a **definite** performance hit to your insert  activity for a possible saving in the performance of aggregating queries.

The good practice is to just run the counts when you need the summaries. Tune the queries if you need to.

If you think you really are going to be querying the summary data often enough for the workload to be a problem you should consider building materialized views for the summary queries. Then, when [you enable query rewrites](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-4312A6E5-4DB0-4FD8-ADA8-5A0D833D2522.htm#REFRN10176), Oracle will transparently query the materialized view if it can satisfy the query rather than re-running the aggregations. This is a technique which is used a lot in data warehouses, but there's no reason not to use it in OLTP environments if you really have the data volumes to justify it. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/qrbasic.htm#DWHSG018).

Generally, try the simplest thing which could work first. Only look to do something different (like building a materialized view for aggregations) when you know you have a demonstrable problem with performance.

Comment: Thank you. I will try with simple approach and then if needed I will try using MVs. We are on 12.2, so I think I can also use real time MVs.

Comment: Data sumarizing over more than the row it's in does not violate normalization.

Comment: @philipxy - you're right of course. I've been schooled so long in it being bad practice in OLTP environments that I forgot it's not actually forbidden.

Comment: I'd agree it's bad design & redundant & begs a constraint; but my point is that it isn't the kind of bad design & redundancy & constraint-begging addressed by normalization.